# ReactJS react-router-dom ^5.3.0 not rendering components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom, router

I was using this code without the `BrowserRouter` component wrapping the `Switch` and it worked well. When did some jest testing I have got the following error `Invariant failed: Browser history needs a DOM` which says that the `Link` component cannot be used outside a router. Indeed, I was not using the router. When I have added the router, the url is changing but components are not redered properly. Did I make it correct?

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';


export const _routes = [
    {
        component: Home,
        path: '/',
        exact: true
    },
    {
        component: Orders,
        path: '/orders',
        exact: false
    },
    {
        component: OrderConfirm,
        path: '/order-confirm',
        exact: false
    }
]

const App = () => <>
    <Navbar />
    <Router>
        <Switch>
            {_routes.map(route => <Route key={route.path} path={route.path} component={route.component} exact={route.exact} />)}
        </Switch>
    </Router>
</>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work as expected :

```
export const _routes = [
    {
        component: 'Home',
        path: '/',
        exact: true
    },
    {
        component: 'Orders',
        path: '/orders',
        exact: false
    },
    {
        component: 'OrderConfirm',
        path: '/order-confirm',
        exact: false
    }
]



const App = () => <>
    <Navbar />
    <Router>
        <Switch>
            {_routes.map(route => <Route key={route.path} path={route.path} component=require(`./components/${route.component}`).default exact={route.exact} />)}
        </Switch>
    </Router>
</>
```

I assume that your components are inside `components` package (this`./components/${route.component}` shoud be path to your component)